# Rav Yaakov Moshe Hillel and wearing tzitzios out

Tags: rabbis, tzitzis, mysticism-kabbalah, tallit-katan

Does someone know anything about Rav Yaakov Moshe Hillel shlita hamekubal stating that tzitzios should be worn outside the clothes? I read it once but without any sources on a web forum.
It would be quite surprising as one of the argument to tuck them is based on kabbalah and the Arizal.

Comment: No answer to offer, but being an admirer of Rav Hillel shlit"a, I would love to know his opinion.

Comment: This is a great question, because the Mishnah Berurah really strongly criticizes those who tuck them in. And that's putting it mildly.

Comment: @SethJ Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef zt'l criticizes those who do not tuck them in.

Comment: @SethJ Eyewitness testimony reports that the Chafetz Chaim himself wore his _tzitzit_ in.

Comment: @mevakesh maybe he had a reason. But I can tell you what I saw when I learned it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In his book Geburat HaAri (pg. 137) he brings the AriZal and explains that according to him they should be exposed because in Shaar HaKawanot (7c) the Ari says that there is a Miswa to behold the Sisiot (see Debarim 15:39).

He expounds on this immensely in his Sefer Wayashov HaYam (vol. 1 Siman 3).

Comment: @HachamGabriel Are those both your accounts?

Comment: -1 Because one is not allowed to learn two things out from the same pasuk.  Rashi already tells us that "uRe'item oto" refers to the necessity of them being worn during the daytime.  If one was allowed to learn two things out from the same pasuk, then why do the tannaim disagree in the second chapter of M. Berakhot, where Shema Yisrael is understood to mean cause your ear to hear it, or say it in a language that you hear, i.e. that you understand.  The thing is that the two tannaim who say this are arguing with each other and not agreeing, implying that there is only one way to darshen.

Comment: @Adam: but are these really two separate things? Being able to see the tzitzis in itself implies both that it's during a time when you're able to see (so not at night), and that they should be visible. This is different than the two meanings of שמע, where hearing and understanding are orthogonal (you can hear something without understanding it, or conversely, understand it - thinking it in your mind - without hearing it).

Comment: @Alex -  I believe that they are in fact orthogonal!  If you hold that tzitzis must be tucked in, then you are not able to see them (as they are inside).  And if you hold that they must be seen, then why do you maintain as well that they are required to be worn at night when it is dark and therefore concealed by darkness?  A beged yom can be worn tucked in during the daytime or nighttime and still be defined as a beged yom.

Comment: @Adam you are arguing with the smak who counts it is a separate miswa.

Comment: @HachamGabriel - What?

Comment: @Adam the Sma"k counts "uritem oto" as a separate Miswa.

Comment: @HachamGabriel - I didn't realize it was Roshei Teivos.  You're talking about the Semaq.  Sefer mitzvos hakatan.

I could be wrong, but I think that listing "uritem oto" as one of taryag mitzvot would definitely be considered a minority opinion.  Do you know if the other big lists of taryag mitzvot list it as well.  I don't think that they do.

Comment: @Adam Arizal...HaRav Yaakov Moshe Hilel says (Wayashov Hayam 1:3:3) "according to all the Posekim it is Miswat Aseh."

Comment: @HachamGabriel - Not only is he sephardic, but he is also an acharon.  What about the poskim who are rishonim?  I don't think they even mention it.  Some of the geonim do but then nothing until achronim.

Comment: @Adam: true, I had forgotten that the Arizal says tzitzis should be worn at night too. But okay, then, according to him that leaves the words וראיתם אותו available to teach us that one should look at them constantly (when it is possible to do so, obviously) - so there still is only one thing being derived from these words.

Comment: And about your conversation with @HachamGabriel whether וראיתם אותו is a mitzvah: it's true that Rambam (and, following him, Chinuch) don't count it separately, but that is probably because they view it as a detail of the general mitzvah to wear tzitzis. They might still well agree that with these words the Torah is telling us to do something with the tzitzis.

Comment: See Wayashov Hayam 1:3:3 as I already mentioned.

Comment: @Alex two comments above you made a great point.

Answer (score 1):

It may be interesting to note, I once saw in his a yeshiva a Scanning of hand written note from Rav Yitchak Keduri Ztz"l agreeing with this ruling and the argument that Rav Hillel puts forth in vayashov Hayam, also a photo of the Baba sali with very long sitzit that where hanging below his gown.
Rav Hillel (because of a seeming contradiction in the kitvei haArizal) believes this practice is an authentic Kabalistic one,

Comment: Can you try to find the picture of the Baba Sali? That would be very interesting to see.

Comment: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CLpSC.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CLpSC.jpg) Tzitzit of the Baba Sali. As you see that se wore them outside according the real kabbalistic shita.